# Laravel - eloquent complex where clause

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Could somebody help how can I accomplish something like this below

```
->where("YEAR( date_field )", '>=', 2014)
```

`date_field` is a mysql date like: `2014-03-22`

Comment: By the time I've resolved using this: `->whereRaw('YEAR( date_field ) >= ?', array(2014))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A raw() command should work](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#basic-usage):

```
->whereRaw('YEAR(date_field) >= ?', array(2014))
```

Comment: This throws: argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::whereRaw() must be an array, string given

Comment: Sorry - fixed my answer. The other option is Antonios answer aswell.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, I needed to achieve exactly what you've written.

Answer (score 1):

The less raw you use the better, Laravel uses Carbon as its DateTime internal class, so you can:

```
$year = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate(2014)->firstOfYear();
```

It will return a date like this:

```
2014-01-01 00:00:00
```

So, if your are filtering by the year and you need all records starting in 2014, you can do this:

```
->where('date_field', '>=', $year)
```

Don't forget you can create helper functions or methods:

```
public function year($year)
{
    return \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate(2014)->firstOfYear();    
}
```

And then just:

```
->where('date_field', '>=', year(2014))
```

Comment: My problem is that I need only the year of the date_field like `'YEAR( date_field)'`

Comment: You are filtering by the year or not? If you are, you can surely use a date.

Comment: I would like to achieve this exactly (just got the answer): `->whereRaw('YEAR(date_field) >= ?', array(2014))`, I don't see how will this work using your solution or maybe we misunderstood eachother.

Comment: Was a bit tired yesterday, I see what you mean no and that could be a solution also, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Raw is an option of course, but since v4.1.25 you can use following methods as well:

```
->whereYear('column', '>=', 2014);

// and for month or day:
->whereMonth('column', '>=', 5);
->whereDay('column', '>=', 15);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the project which I'm working on is in v4.1.24, but good to know :)